# Conversion of Hex octets to Unicode

Tags: iphone, unicode, nsstring

```
NSString* code = @"\x03\x7e";
const char *cString = [code cStringUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
NSData* unicodeData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cString length:strlen(cString)];
NSString* convertedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:unicodeData encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
```

I’d like the convertedString to be the unicode value of \x03\x7e which is a greek question mark (looks kind of like a semicolon). My converted string ends up just as an empty string…
Any idea how I can do this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Sample Code:**

```
NSString *code = @"\x03\x7e";
NSData *data = [code dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
NSString *codeNew = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
```